# Messaging system broken, "undefined method 'email' for nil:NilClass" after Heroku push

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, heroku, devise

I created a really basic messaging system from scratch in Rails. Users can simply message each other with a title and body, with their "username" being their email.

My error message `undefined method "email" for nil:NilClass` hits at `message.sender.email` when I go to access my messages index. The sender, who is the current_owner, has `:email` defined in the schema and when I register my users with Devise I have no problem with the email registering. When I go to send a new message, I don't get a specific error message but get a generic Devise warning that the message did not go through. In pry, it was not reaching the form at all when I accessed the messages page.

**Solution:** I had a mentor check over my issue and it turned out to be bad data screwing with my form. We went into rails console and found a message without full sender_id info that was causing the issue. Once we went and deleted the message, my feature issue was resolved. Here is a screenshot of the fix in rails console: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdjwZ.png

Message index.html.erb -

```
 <% @received_messages.each do |message| %>
   <li>
     **<%= message.sender.email %><br>**
     <%= message.title %><br>
     <%= message.body %>
   </li>
  <% end %>
  </ol>
</div>
```

messagescontroller.rb:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
 def index
  @received_messages = Message.where(recipient: current_owner)
  @sent_messages = Message.where(sender: current_owner)
 end

 def show
  @messages = Message.all
 end

 def new
  @message = Message.new
  @friend = Friendship.find(params[:friendship_id])
 end

 def create
  friendship = Friendship.find(params[:friendship_id])
  pet = Pet.find(params[:pet_id])
  @message = Message.create(message_params)
  @message.sender = current_owner
  @message.recipient = pet.owner

 if @message.save
  flash[:notice] = 'Your message was sent!'
  redirect_to messages_path
 else
  flash.now[:notice] = 'Your message could not be sent.'
  render :new
 end
end

def destroy
 @message = current_owner.messages.find(params[:id])
 @message.destroy
 flash[:notice] = 'Message deleted.'
  redirect_to owner_messages_path
 end

 private

 def message_params
  params.require(:message).permit(:body, :title)
 end
end
```

Routes -

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 devise_for :owners

 resources :friendships, only: [:index, :destroy]

 resources :messages, only: [:index]

 resources :pets do
  resources :friendships, only: :create do
   resources :messages, only: [:new, :create]
  end
 end

 resources :owners do
  resources :pets, shallow: true
 end

root to: "pets#index"
```

Model Associations -

```
 class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner
  belongs_to :friend, class_name: "Pet"

  has_many :messages, as: :friendships, source: :owner
 end

 class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: 'Owner'
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: 'Owner'

  validates :sender_id, presence: true
  validates :recipient_id, presence: true
 end

 class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pets
  has_many :friendships

  has_many :friends, through: :friendships
  has_many :inverse_friendships, class_name: "Friendship", foreign_key: "friend_id"

  has_many :messages, through: :friendships
 end

 class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner
  has_many :friends, class_name: 'Pet'
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
@message = Message.create(message_params)
```

to

```
@message = Message.new(message_params)
```

If that doesn't work, why not assign sender and recipient in your form with a hidden field?

**Edit**

Using hidden fields in your form

```
<%= form_for @message do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :sender, value: current_owner.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :recipient, value: pet.owner.id %>
  # your other fields
<% end %>
```

Also, are you sure @received_messages isn't empty?

**Edit**

Specify foreign keys.

```
class Message
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: 'Owner', foreign_key: :sender_id
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: 'Owner', foreign_key: :recipient_id
```

Comment: Changing the line to include `new` instead of `create` didn't fix it. I think your other suggestion may work. How exactly would I format that with the hidden field?

Comment: can you show how you defined your associations? the has_many and all of that, please. i will add the hidden fields to my answer.

Comment: I have included my model associations up in my post now.

Comment: You aren't specifying foreign keys for your models. I'll updates my answer.

Comment: Good call on the foreign keys. I added those guys in and now get a new error when I go to post a message instead of having it go through and then show an error that it wasn't successful. When I try to accesss my new message form, it hits `<%= f.hidden_field :recipient, value: pet.owner.id %>` and gives me `undefined local variable or method 'pet'` now. I'm really unsure of why it's giving me that b/c I can add and edit pets, fine. So it might be the way pets and owners are being associated as 'friends'?